# No whois server is known for this kind of object

Tags: whois, pywhois

I get the error message when calling from PHP:

```
$content= exec("whois sanei-office.com");
```

I get the message:

```
No whois server is known for this kind of object
```

But when calling from terminal (same linux server), the request works.

Comment: Why did you tag the question `pywhois`? Are you using python or php?

Comment: i used php , but i can switch to python if necessary... could it have to do with user rights?

Comment: Be it PHP or Python, do not escape to the shell to do whois queries, you have libraries in both languages to perform whois queries.